# Qdrant library in angular project compiling problem

Tags: angular, qdrantclient

I installed @qdrant/js-client-rest in angular project.

After compiling I get this error:

Error: node_modules/@qdrant/js-client-rest/dist/types/api-client.d.ts:4:51 - error TS1005: '>' expected.
4 export type Client = ReturnType<typeof Fetcher.for>;
~

Error: node_modules/@qdrant/js-client-rest/dist/types/api-client.d.ts:4:58 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
4 export type Client = ReturnType<typeof Fetcher.for>;
~

Error: node_modules/@qdrant/js-client-rest/dist/types/api-client.d.ts:4:59 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
4 export type Client = ReturnType<typeof Fetcher.for>;

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to a later version of typescript should fix this issue.

I was on 4.5.4 and upgraded to 5.3.3

Other dependencies may also need to be bumped depending on what is in your package.json.